# Which mobile device is appropriate as a utility tool for a web master?

Tags: mobile, iphone, android

Basically, I'm looking for a device to use on the road and I would prefer to not have to sit down for the majority of the tasks (which rules out netbooks, in my mind). I'm also hoping to spend less than $500.

This is what I'd like to "capably" be able to do on the device:

- Browse the web in non-mobile format, flash is a plus
- Email, chat, etc
- Have access to a decent text editor and ftp OR a browser that supports BESPIN/ACE
- Some sort of SSH support

I'm looking at rooted Android phones and iPhone/iPads... though the phone aspect is only icing (it would be cool to consolidate the two devices and have net access through cell networks, but I'm not married to the idea).

Are there cheap linux tablets that are ready for prime-time yet? I suppose that would be ideal.

All suggestions welcome!

Answer (score 1):

iPhone and iPads don't support flash and the only SSH you get is on either jailbroken (and that isn't very good, or so I have heard) or on a server. There is support for ftp and svn as long as you don't want to actually run the files locally. I use my ipad for edits on the go that I can then upload and view on my server.

One option is the Nokia Internet Tablet. I own one and it is a completely open version of linux. The keyboard isn't great, so don't expect super fast typing. I have an older version so I can't say whether the new ones except flash, but they do display the browser in none mobile versions. Also, you should have a good basis in linux before getting it as you will be messing with the system to do the more fancy stuff.

Also, I know that at&t was advertising a tablet Android device. I have never used android for ssh and such, but it can view full web pages.

Answer (score 0):

Android + [Rooting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rooting_%28Android_OS%29). Makes you life much easier ;-)